# Represent a list of Enums bitwise as an Int

Tags: haskell, enums, bit-manipulation

In order to save user-account permissions externally (e.g. in DB), I want to represent a list of elements of a enumeration that have a derived `Enum` instance as an `Int`.
Every bit of the number is seen as a flag (or Boolean) denoting if the i-th element is present in the list.
Putting it in different words - every power of 2 represents one element and the sum of such powers an *unique* list of elements.

Example:

```
data Permissions = IsAllowedToLogin   -- 1
                 | IsModerator        -- 2
                 | IsAdmin            -- 4
                 deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Show) 

enumsToInt [IsAllowedToLogin, IsAdmin] == 1 + 4 == 5

intToEnums 3 == intToEnums (1 + 2) == [IsAllowedToLogin, IsModerator]
```

---

The function converting such a list into an `Int` is quite easy to write:

```
enumsToInt :: (Enum a, Eq a) => [a] -> Int
enumsToInt = foldr (\p acc -> acc + 2 ^ fromEnum p) 0 . nub
```

*Note that the accepted answer contains a much more effective implementation.*

What really troubles me is the reversing function. I can imagine it should have this type:

```
intToEnums :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => Int -> [a]
intToEnums = undefined               -- What I'm asking about
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: For starters, have you looked at [the `Data.Bits` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Bits.html)?

Comment: @C. A. McCann No I haven't! Do you think it will be useful?

Comment: I don't think it has anything that does exactly what you want (though it seems like something that should be there) but it has a bunch of bitwise operations that will make things way easier for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following is a complete solution. It should perform better as it's implementation is based on bitwise rather than arithmetic operations, which is a much more effective approach. The solution also does its best to generalize things.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
import Data.Bits
import Control.Monad

data Permission = IsAllowedToLogin   -- 1
                | IsModerator        -- 2
                | IsAdmin            -- 4
                deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Show) 

class ToBitMask a where 
  toBitMask :: a -> Int
  -- | Using a DefaultSignatures extension to declare a default signature with
  -- an `Enum` constraint without affecting the constraints of the class itself.
  default toBitMask :: Enum a => a -> Int
  toBitMask = shiftL 1 . fromEnum

instance ToBitMask Permission

instance ( ToBitMask a ) => ToBitMask [a] where 
  toBitMask = foldr (.|.) 0 . map toBitMask

-- | Not making this a typeclass, since it already generalizes over all 
-- imaginable instances with help of `MonadPlus`.
fromBitMask :: 
  ( MonadPlus m, Enum a, Bounded a, ToBitMask a ) => 
    Int -> m a
fromBitMask bm = msum $ map asInBM $ enumFrom minBound where 
  asInBM a = if isInBitMask bm a then return a else mzero

isInBitMask :: ( ToBitMask a ) => Int -> a -> Bool
isInBitMask bm a = let aBM = toBitMask a in aBM == aBM .&. bm
```

Running it with the following

```
main = do
  print (fromBitMask 0 :: [Permission])
  print (fromBitMask 1 :: [Permission])
  print (fromBitMask 2 :: [Permission])
  print (fromBitMask 3 :: [Permission])
  print (fromBitMask 4 :: [Permission])
  print (fromBitMask 5 :: [Permission])
  print (fromBitMask 6 :: [Permission])
  print (fromBitMask 7 :: [Permission])

  print (fromBitMask 0 :: Maybe Permission)
  print (fromBitMask 1 :: Maybe Permission)
  print (fromBitMask 2 :: Maybe Permission)
  print (fromBitMask 4 :: Maybe Permission)
```

outputs

```
[]
[IsAllowedToLogin]
[IsModerator]
[IsAllowedToLogin,IsModerator]
[IsAdmin]
[IsAllowedToLogin,IsAdmin]
[IsModerator,IsAdmin]
[IsAllowedToLogin,IsModerator,IsAdmin]
Nothing
Just IsAllowedToLogin
Just IsModerator
Just IsAdmin
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would it be possible to add default definitions to the classes, so I could simply write `instance ToBitMask Permission`??? Of course assuming that `Permission` permissions is already instance of `Enum` and `Bounded`.

Comment: @Jakub Made updates to generalize it even more, in case you're interested.

Comment: Great! Now I can really use this with any type, not even spending a sec on thinking how to implement the functions.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov This could be a library of its own! It's perfect!

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there's something on hackage that does this already, but it's simple enough to hand-roll your own using [the `Data.Bits` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Bits.html).

You can simplify `enumsToInt` to just something like `foldl' (.|.) . map (bit . fromEnum)`, i.e., convert to integer indices and then to single bits, then fold with bitwise OR. If nothing else, this saves you from worrying about removing duplicates.

For `intToEnums` there's nothing incredibly convenient, but for a quick solution you can do something like `filter (testBit foo . fromEnum) [minBound .. maxBound]`. This of course only works for `Bounded` types and presumes that the enum doesn't have more values than the external type has bits and that `fromEnum` uses consecutive integers starting from 0, but it sounds like you're starting with all that as a premise here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[EnumSet](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/enumset/0.0.4/doc/html/Data-EnumSet.html) is probably exactly what you want.  It even has an `intToEnums` function (though it appears to only work consistently with `T Integer a` of the types I have tried - in particular, `T Int Char` gives unexpected results) and would not be expected to recreate duplicate entries after serializing/deserializing (given that its a set), while a list may carry that expectation.

Comment: Yeah, you're gonna need a bigger `Int` for that. Unless your machine uses 128-bit words you're not even going to fit basic ASCII characters into that `EnumSet`. Try `Ordering` or something like `(Bool, Bool)` if you want to use `Int`s.